# How to update lot of files with Github API?

Tags: php, github-api

I need in updating lot of files in my repo via php-script.
I read api documentation and i can update any file with PUT request

```
....
$update = array("message"=>"COMMIT", "content"=>base64_encode($test), "sha"=>$json["sha"]);
put(url, $data_string);
....
```

But if i need to update 2000 files? It's too not convenient. Are there ways to manipulate with files by single request? And if yes, can smb give sample of such code?

Comment: You need to update what.github or your local repository?

Comment: github ofc. my local repository doesn't have github api :)

Comment: You want to upload your code to github.Right? If yes then you need a guthub account for that.and need to install git in your local machine.

Comment: Man, pls. I've already registred account and i can update any file by http put request. Now i need to do it no one by one.